# Not able to use the another field value in random function

Tags: angularjs, api, testing, automated-tests, dummy-data

I am generating the data from the Mockaroo - Random data generator

Scenario is :

I have one field **Income** (value can be 0 to 99999) and I have another field **Net Income** i want value of this field must be less then Income

So, any one can suggest me formula or regular expression for this Which support in **Mockaroo**.But thing that i can not use the static formula like Income - 10 or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the field coming to the random function they were considering them as String so i need to cast them.

To Cast to integer formula is : **.to_i**

So, solution for this is in mockaroo is

Select ***Regular expression*** then write in field : **{{Income}}**

Then select the ***fx*** and write the condition : **if true then {{this}}-random(0,Income.to_i) end**

if anybody has doubt just do the comment i will reply you soon